# How can geometric algebra blades be implemented in c?

Tags: c, graphics, geometry, algebra

A k-blade in n-dimension space has (n \choose k) bases.
 For example: let k = 3, n = 5, then our 3-blade in 5-space can be implemented as:

```
typedef long double real_t;

typedef struct blade_5d_3_t_
{
    real_t e1e2e3; /* 1 */
    real_t e1e2e4; /* 2 */
    real_t e1e2e5; /* 3 */
    real_t e1e3e4; /* 4 */
    real_t e1e3e5; /* 5 */
    real_t e1e4e5; /* 6 */
    real_t e2e3e4; /* 7 */
    real_t e2e3e5; /* 8 */
    real_t e2e4e4; /* 9 */
    real_t e3e4e5; /* 10 = 5 choose 3 */
}
blade_5d_3_t;
```

This `blade_5d_3_t` type means a 3-blade in 5 space.
We can implement `blade_nd_k_t` in the same way.

If one want to implement all (k,n) blades for 0<=n<=5 and k<=n, then (5+1)*5/2 types of different blades have to be implemented.

Now i want to implement my blade structs for some large n, then define functions on the space of blades.

Is it possible to achieve my goal elegantly in c?

Comment: No, it would be at least inelegant and hard to tackle. Use a more powerful language as C++, and have a look at some algebra library, there exist some, may be one with blades?

Comment: Yep I think templates in C++ would be ideal for this. In C you are stuck only with macros which is most likely not enough for this case (at least not elegantly)

Comment: I played around with this and my approach was to write a program to write the source of a library for doing ga calculations. The generated source of the library was not so elegant, but that doesn't seem so important to me; the elegance comes from ga itself. However large n will inevitably lead to large code -- you have a 2^n dimensional space with n grades.

Comment: @dmuir heh :) I am using the same approach in hideous cases like [GLSL `?vec?`  datatypes  in C++](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6055/6868) ... source code generating source code is a strong tool once acustom to it ... sadly this can not be done on the runtime which is why I did not mention it in previous comment...

Comment: Hardcoding the blade names into variable names is a bad approach. Consider an array or a dictionary.